# Code coverage for constructor

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, constructor

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class PractitionerQTriggerHandler extends Domain{
  
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param  records List of Records
     */
    public EhrPractitionerQualiTriggerHandler(List<PractitionerQualification__c> records) {
        super(records);
    }
    
    public override void onBeforeInsert() {
        List<PractitionerQualification__c> pqRecs = (List<PractitionerQualification__c>) this.records;
        EhrPractitionerQualiTriggerHelper.populateOnekeyValue(pqRecs);        
    }
    
    public override void onBeforeUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> oldMap) {
       List<PractitionerQualification__c> pqRecs = (List<PractitionerQualification__c>) this.records;
       EhrPractitionerQualiTriggerHelper.populateOnekeyValue(pqRecs);  
    }
  }
```

Test class:

```
 @isTest
  public class PractitionerTest {
  @isTest
  static void createTestData() {
        
        Practitioner__c EhrPractitioner = TestDataFactory.EhrPractitioner('Chicago', True);
 
        List<EhrPractitionerQualification__c> EhrList = new List<PractitionerQualification__c>{
            TestDataFactory.EhrPractitionerQualification(EhrPractitioner.id, True)
        };   
            List<PractitionerQualification__c> EhrpList = new List<PractitionerQualification__c>();
            for(PractitionerQualification__c Ad :EhrList){
                Ad.SystemId__c = 'SourceSystem';
                EhrpList.add(Ad);
            }
        Update EhrpList;
        Test.startTest();
            PractitionerTriggerHelper.populateValue(EhrpList);                
        Test.stopTest();
}
 }
```

Not able to code coverage for the constructor part in above Handler class.

```
    */
public EhrPractitionerQualiTriggerHandler(List<PractitionerQualification__c> records) {
    super(records);
}
```

Can someone please help what I am missing in test class?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your code path, you'd need to have:

```
new EhrPractitionerQualiTriggerHandler(records);
```

I don't see it in your current unit test, so you'll have to check your trigger and see if it's doing something like this (my best guess would be specifically `new EhrPractitionerQualiTriggerHandler(Trigger.new)`). If not, then it's possible you're either using your trigger handler framework wrong, or this code is superfluous.